# p5.js Pong game

Tags: distance, pong, p5.js

I am really sorry for this stupid question but i don't know what i should do.
I tried so many things nothing works.
I try to calculate the distance between playerx and the width of playerx.
Can someone just correct my code so i can understand it please try not to explain it.

```
var playerx = 0;
var z = 0;
var playery = 750;

var ball = {
x: 400,
y: 400,
speedx: 2,
speedy: 3,
};

function setup() {
createCanvas(800,800);}

function draw(){
background(0);
ball1();
player();
click();
wall();
bounce();
hit();
}

function hit(){
var AA = dist(playerx,playery,player.x + 200,playery)
var BB = dist(ball.x,ball.y,AA,).    

 if (BB <= 20){
  ball.speedy = -7;
 }
}

function ball1(){
fill(255);
rect(ball.x,ball.y,20,20);
}

function bounce(){
ball.x += ball.speedx;
ball.y += ball.speedy;
if (ball.x>800){
ball.speedx = -2;
}else if (ball.x<0){
ball.speedx = 3; 
}else if (ball.y>800){
ball.speedy = -3;
} else if(ball.y<0){
ball.speedy = 2;
}
}

function player(){
fill(255);
rect(playerx,playery,200,20);
}

function click(){
if(keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
 playerx += z;
 z = 3;
} else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW){
 playerx += z;
 z = -3;
}
}

function wall(){
if (playerx > 600){
 playerx = 600;
} else if (playerx < 1){
 playerx = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Why did you ask someone here to correct your code for you? Not to help you correct your own code? Did you consider StackOverflow like some free software creating service?

Answer (score 0):

check this library, it contains the code for collision detection:

https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D

```js
var playerx = 400;
var z = 0;
var playery = 750;

var ball = {
  x: 400,
  y: 400,
  speedx: 2,
  speedy: 3,
};

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  ball1();
  player();
  click();
  wall();
  bounce();
  hit();
}

function hit() {
 if(checkCollision(playerx, playery, 200, 20, ball.x, ball.y, 20)){
   ball.speedy = -7;
   console.log("colliding");
 }
}

function ball1() {
  fill(255);
  ellipse(ball.x, ball.y, 20, 20);
}

function bounce() {
  ball.x += ball.speedx;
  ball.y += ball.speedy;
  if (ball.x > 800) {
    ball.speedx = -2;
  } else if (ball.x < 0) {
    ball.speedx = 3;
  } else if (ball.y > 800) {
    ball.speedy = -3;
  } else if (ball.y < 0) {
    ball.speedy = 2;
  }
}

function player() {
  fill(255);
  rect(playerx, playery, 200, 20);
}

function click() {
  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    playerx += z;
    z = 3;
  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    playerx += z;
    z = -3;
  }
}

function wall() {
  if (playerx > 600) {
    playerx = 600;
  } else if (playerx < 1) {
    playerx = 1;
  }
}

function checkCollision(rx, ry, rw, rh, cx, cy, diameter) {
  //2d
  // temporary variables to set edges for testing
  var testX = cx;
  var testY = cy;

  // which edge is closest?
  if (cx < rx){         testX = rx       // left edge
  }else if (cx > rx+rw){ testX = rx+rw  }   // right edge

  if (cy < ry){         testY = ry       // top edge
  }else if (cy > ry+rh){ testY = ry+rh }   // bottom edge

  // // get distance from closest edges
  var distance = dist(cx,cy,testX,testY)

  // if the distance is less than the radius, collision!
  if (distance <= diameter/2) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it showed a simple example of its usage.